# How to perform a service in a new process?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to perform a service in a new process, use android:process=":myservice" usage, but it does not perform a new process.
I have already tried:
my service statement in manifest xml code:

```
<service android:name="com.example.huangli.mytest2.MyService"
android:process=":MyService"></service>
```

start this service use below code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

i check my android device which apps are running,just display one process one service. my expectation is two process one service. i want to know where is my error.

Comment: just `Log.d` the pids of your calling `Activity` and your `Service`

Comment: Try adding `android:process=':activityProcName'` (with a different process name) to the *activity* declarations. I'm quite sure `android:process=':procName'` does not imply that the service is *alone* in its process (the apps' activities can still run alongside the service in the process).

Comment: and now, do you know where your error is?

Comment: yes, i had fixed it. thanks.